# How to know which fareComponent is associated with a segment in BargainFinderMaxRS

Tags: rest, sabre

The rest api BargainFinderMaxRS groupedItineraryResponse object gives me the legs and their schedules (segments). It also gives me the fareComponents in the passengerInfo. But I can't figure out which fareComponent belongs to which flight segment. I don't see any identifier, like 'id' or 'ref', that links a specific flight segment to it's fareComponent. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

```
legs: [
  0: {
    id: 1,
    schedules: [
      0: {...},
      1: {...}
    ]
  },
  1: {
    id: 2,
    schedules: [
      0: {...}
    ]
  }
]

...

passengerInfo: {
  fareComponents: [
    0: {...},
    1: {...},
    2: {...}
  ]
}
```

**EDIT** Ok, I thought I understood how to match Legs to FareComponents, but I'm still having issues. Some times it seems like the array indexes of legs and fareComponents match up, but sometimes they don't.

In the itnerary below the first leg has 2 segments, and the second leg is non-stop. But the first fareComponent has 1 segment, and the second component has 2. Clearly fareComponent2 belongs to Leg1

Here's my Legs array from BFM response object:

```
"legs": [
{
  "ref": 3,
  "id": 3,
  "schedules": [
    {
      "ref": 13,
      "id": 13,
      "dotRating": "9",
      "frequency": "SMTWT**",
      "stopCount": 0,
      "eTicketable": true,
      "totalMilesFlown": 2556,
      "departure": {
        "airport": "HNL",
        "city": "HNL",
        "state": "HI",
        "country": "US",
        "time": "20:55:00-10:00",
        "terminal": "2"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "airport": "LAX",
        "city": "LAX",
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "US",
        "time": "05:18:00-07:00",
        "terminal": "2",
        "dateAdjustment": 1
      },
      "carrier": {
        "marketing": "DL",
        "marketingFlightNumber": 1212,
        "operating": "DL",
        "operatingFlightNumber": 1212,
        "equipment": {
          "code": "739",
          "typeForFirstLeg": "N",
          "typeForLastLeg": "N"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "ref": 12,
      "departureDateAdjustment": 1,
      "id": 12,
      "dotRating": "8",
      "frequency": "SMTWT**",
      "stopCount": 0,
      "eTicketable": true,
      "totalMilesFlown": 953,
      "departure": {
        "airport": "LAX",
        "city": "LAX",
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "US",
        "time": "09:38:00-07:00",
        "terminal": "3"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "airport": "SEA",
        "city": "SEA",
        "state": "WA",
        "country": "US",
        "time": "12:27:00-07:00"
      },
      "carrier": {
        "marketing": "DL",
        "marketingFlightNumber": 2540,
        "operating": "DL",
        "operatingFlightNumber": 2540,
        "equipment": {
          "code": "739",
          "typeForFirstLeg": "N",
          "typeForLastLeg": "N"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "ref": 6,
  "id": 6,
  "schedules": [
    {
      "ref": 10,
      "id": 10,
      "dotRating": "9",
      "frequency": "****TF*",
      "stopCount": 0,
      "eTicketable": true,
      "totalMilesFlown": 2676,
      "departure": {
        "airport": "SEA",
        "city": "SEA",
        "state": "WA",
        "country": "US",
        "time": "08:20:00-07:00"
      },
      "arrival": {
        "airport": "HNL",
        "city": "HNL",
        "state": "HI",
        "country": "US",
        "time": "11:29:00-10:00",
        "terminal": "2"
      },
      "carrier": {
        "marketing": "DL",
        "marketingFlightNumber": 1887,
        "operating": "DL",
        "operatingFlightNumber": 1887,
        "equipment": {
          "code": "753",
          "typeForFirstLeg": "N",
          "typeForLastLeg": "N"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

]

Here is the fareComponents array:

```
"fareComponents": [
            {
              "ref": 1,
              "segments": [
                {
                  "segment": {
                    "bookingCode": "V",
                    "cabinCode": "Y",
                    "mealCode": "D",
                    "seatsAvailable": 4,
                    "availabilityBreak": true
                  }
                }
              ],
              "id": 1,
              "governingCarrier": "DL",
              "fareAmount": 137.31,
              "fareCurrency": "USD",
              "fareBasisCode": "VA0SLOME/LN75",
              "farePassengerType": "JCB",
              "ticketDesignator": "LN75",
              "publishedFareAmount": 274.62,
              "negotiatedFare": true,
              "privateFare": true,
              "directionality": "FROM",
              "direction": "WH",
              "notValidAfter": "2019-08-31",
              "applicablePricingCategories": "5 10 15 16 18 25 35",
              "vendorCode": "ATP",
              "fareTypeBitmap": "0E",
              "fareType": "SIP",
              "fareTariff": "191",
              "fareRule": "8694"
            },
            {
              "ref": 5,
              "segments": [
                {
                  "segment": {
                    "bookingCode": "V",
                    "cabinCode": "Y",
                    "mealCode": "B",
                    "seatsAvailable": 4,
                    "availabilityBreak": true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "segment": {
                    "bookingCode": "V",
                    "cabinCode": "Y",
                    "mealCode": "B",
                    "seatsAvailable": 9,
                    "availabilityBreak": true
                  }
                }
              ],
              "id": 5,
              "governingCarrier": "DL",
              "fareAmount": 137.31,
              "fareCurrency": "USD",
              "fareBasisCode": "VA0SLOME/LN75",
              "farePassengerType": "JCB",
              "ticketDesignator": "LN75",
              "publishedFareAmount": 274.62,
              "negotiatedFare": true,
              "privateFare": true,
              "directionality": "TO",
              "direction": "WH",
              "notValidAfter": "2019-08-31",
              "applicablePricingCategories": "5 10 15 16 18 25 35",
              "vendorCode": "ATP",
              "fareTypeBitmap": "0E",
              "fareType": "SIP",
              "fareTariff": "191",
              "fareRule": "8694"
            }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bargain Finder responses doesn't match prices with legs. Itineraries group segments (legs), and each itinerary have its own price.

Edit: I misunderstood the question. You are not missing something, you are right. First, you need to group legs by it's ref value, using "legs" attribute of itinerary. You need to sort segment legs using that information, after that you'll see legs count and fare component --> segment attribute count is the same. Also their indexes are same too. I mean you have 3 leg after sorting:

leg1
leg2
leg3

and you have 3 fare component:

fareComponent1
fareComponent2
fareComponent3

Here is the result:

leg1 own fareComponent1

leg2 own fareComponent2

... and so on. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I needed. I just wasn't sure that it was safe to assume that the index of legs matches up with the index of fareComponents.